# Convert dataframe from one first to another

Tags: r, dataframe

I have a dataframe that looks like this.

```
 > head(zeisel)
  gene_name ClusterName       p
1     GNAI3         ABC 0.29914
2     GNAI3        ACBG 0.33417
3     GNAI3        ACMB 0.21984
4     GNAI3       ACNT1 0.14727
5     GNAI3       ACNT2 0.22205
6     GNAI3        ACOB 0.16913
```

I would like to convert it into this:

[image]

Is there a way to do this? I tried setting the names first, but this would mean iteratively rbinding every row.

For example:

```
#get name of new df
cells <- as.data.frame(table(df$ClusterName))

#now create an empty dataframe. 
unmelted_df <- setNames(data.frame(matrix(ncol = length(cells$Var1), nrow = 0)), as.character(cells$Var1))
```

Is there a way to do this in one step for a massive dataframe?

Comment: Try `tidyr::spread(df, ClusterName, p)` ?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

An option would be to create sequence column and then `spread` into 'wide' format

```
library(tidyverse)
zeisel %>%
    mutate(rn = 1) %>%
    spread(ClusterName, p)
#  gene_name rn     ABC    ACBG    ACMB   ACNT1   ACNT2    ACOB
#1     GNAI3  1 0.29914 0.33417 0.21984 0.14727 0.22205 0.16913
```

---

From the newer version of `tidyr`, `spread` will be deprecated and in place `pivot_wider` can be used

```
zeisel %>% 
    pivot_wider(names_from = 'ClusterName', values_from = 'p')
# A tibble: 1 x 7
#  gene_name   ABC  ACBG  ACMB ACNT1 ACNT2  ACOB
#  <chr>     <dbl> <dbl> <dbl> <dbl> <dbl> <dbl>
#1 GNAI3     0.299 0.334 0.220 0.147 0.222 0.169
```

---

Or using `dcast` from `data.table`

```
library(data.table)
dcast(setDT(zeisel), gene_name ~ ClusterName, value.var = 'p')
#   gene_name     ABC    ACBG    ACMB   ACNT1   ACNT2    ACOB  
#1:     GNAI3 0.29914 0.33417 0.21984 0.14727 0.22205 0.16913
```

#### data

```
zeisel <- structure(list(gene_name = c("GNAI3", "GNAI3", "GNAI3", "GNAI3", 
"GNAI3", "GNAI3"), ClusterName = c("ABC", "ACBG", "ACMB", "ACNT1", 
"ACNT2", "ACOB"), p = c(0.29914, 0.33417, 0.21984, 0.14727, 0.22205, 
0.16913)), class = "data.frame", row.names = c(NA, -6L))
```

Comment: Why use `mutate(rn=1)`?

Comment: @Workhorse  It is not needed, but I thought first that you may need a unique identifier to state that it is the first row (as you provided only the head of the dataset)